# Using self and passing variables

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

This is so elementary, but I'm not understanding why I continue to get 'self is not defined'. How do I pass variables that will be used with multiple methods and print the return value?

```
class math:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
    def add(self):
       return self.x + self.y
x = int(input("first number: "))
y = int(input("second number: "))
print(math.add(x,y))
```

Comment: You need to do `math(x,y).add(x, y)`

Comment: you can also make it a `staticmethod` that way you won't have to instantiate the class. also don't name your class `math` since you are shadowing the actual built-in library, `math`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not a special keyword. It's just passed in automatically if you call your function as a method on an object.

e.g. if you've created your object (I've capitalized the class name, per Python standards)

```py
class Math:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
    def add(self):
       return self.x + self.y

math = Math(x, y)
```

then the following are equivalent:

```py
math.add()
Math.add(math)
```

What you were doing was calling

```py
Math.add(x, y)
```

which is invalid since `Math.add` only takes in one argument (an instance of `Math`).

Answer (score 2):

you have to instantiate your class, use : `math()`

```
print(math(x, y).add())
```

Comment: excellent, thank you for helping with this mind boggling problem.